# Run pairwise fisher's test on all column combinations between two data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I have two data.frames: editCounts and nonEditCounts. These structs are of the same dimensions and contain the same column and row names, but the actual data varies. Below are heads to each:

```
> head(editCounts)
                        Samp0         Samp1       Samp2
chr10_101992307             0             4           3
chr10_101992684             4             0           1
chr10_127480585             0             3           0
chr10_16479385              3             3           3
chr10_73979859              0             3           2
chr10_73979940              0             3           8
> head(nonEditCounts)
                        Samp0         Samp1       Samp2
chr10_101992307             0             4           3
chr10_101992684            15             0           4
chr10_127480585             0             6           0
chr10_16479385              7             7           4
chr10_73979859              0            13           7
chr10_73979940              0            21          10
```

The ultimate goal here is to perform pair-wise fisher tests (using fisher.test()) on each column and row between each of the data.frames. As an output I'd would like to create a table contain the resulting p-values from each pair-wise comparison corresponding to each row name, e.g.:

```
               Samp0_vs_Samp1     Samp0_vs_Samp2     Samp1_vs_Samp2 
chr10_101992307          pval               pval               pval 
chr10_101992684          pval               pval               pval 
chr10_127480585          pval               pval               pval 
chr10_16479385           pval               pval               pval 
chr10_73979859           pval               pval               pval 
...                       ...                ...                ...
```

So, take for example Samp0 and Samp1, the first fisher test would consist of a matrix looking something like this:

```
    > tempMat=matrix(c(editCounts$ERR188028_GBR[1], nonEditCounts$ERR188028_GBR[1],
    +                  editCounts$ERR188035_GBR[1], nonEditCounts$ERR188035_GBR[1]), 2, 2)
    > tempMat
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    0    4
    [2,]    0    4
```

These values correspond to the first row (chr10_101992307). In this case the fisher test would result in a p-value of 1.

I know I can use combn() to compute each column permutation but I'm not exactly sure how to loop though each column, create a contingency table from the 4 values, and run fisher's test. The code I have wrote thus far is listed below; however, it throws an error when trying to create the the tempMat.

```
editCounts    <- read.table("editCountMatrix.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
nonEditCounts <- read.table("nonEditCountMatrix.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.names=1)

pairwiseComb <- combn(names(editCounts),2)

for (j in seq(1,length(pairwiseComb),2)){
  tempCol1 = pairwiseComb[[j]]
  tempCol2 = pairwiseComb[[j+1]]
  cat("Processing: ",tempCol1," vs. ",tempCol2, "\n", sep="") # Prints correctly
  for (i in 1:nrow(editCounts)){
    tempMat=matrix(c(editCounts$tempCol1[i], nonEditCounts$tempCol1[i],
                 editCounts$tempCol2[i], nonEditCounts$tempCol2[i]), 2, 2)
    tempFisher=fisher.test(tempMat, alternative="two.sided")
    pval=tempFisher$p.value
    pvalAdj=p.adjust(pval,method="fdr")
  }
}
```

The error this produces is shown below:

```
Error in matrix(c(editCounts$tempCol1[i], nonEditCounts$tempCol1[i], editCounts$tempCol2[i],  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The error can be corrected by using `[[` or `[` instead of `$`. For example: `editCounts[[tempCol1]][i]` or `editCounts[i, tempCol1]` but not `editCounts$tempCol1[i]`.

Comment: @bdemarest `editCounts[[tempCol1]][i]` seems to work. Although, I'm opting to use our solution below. I've noticed an error when trying to set the columns names of the results matrix when only using two samples. Please see the error below. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposed solution where I have corrected some minor indexing problems with your code, and suggested using a pre-allocated matrix to store the Fisher Exact test results.

```
# Create data.frames using your sample data.
editCounts <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="                        Samp0         Samp1       Samp2
chr10_101992307             0             4           3
chr10_101992684             4             0           1
chr10_127480585             0             3           0
chr10_16479385              3             3           3
chr10_73979859              0             3           2
chr10_73979940              0             3           8")

nonEditCounts <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="                        Samp0         Samp1       Samp2
chr10_101992307             0             4           3
chr10_101992684            15             0           4
chr10_127480585             0             6           0
chr10_16479385              7             7           4
chr10_73979859              0            13           7
chr10_73979940              0            21          10")
```

---

```
pairwiseComb <- combn(names(editCounts), 2)

# Create a matrix to hold results.
results <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(pairwiseComb), nrow=nrow(editCounts))

# Create row and column names to use for indexing/assignment of results.
rownames(results) <- rownames(editCounts)
colnames(results) <- apply(pairwiseComb, 2, 
                           function(x) {paste(x[1], "_vs_", x[2], sep="")})

# Loop over number of column pairs.
for (j in seq(ncol(pairwiseComb))) {
    tempCol1 <- pairwiseComb[1, j]
    tempCol2 <- pairwiseComb[2, j]
    resultsCol <- paste(tempCol1, "_vs_", tempCol2, sep="")
    cols <- c(tempCol1, tempCol2)
    # Loop over rownames.
    for (row in rownames(results)) {
        tempMat <- rbind(   editCounts[row, cols], # Grab values using row and
                         nonEditCounts[row, cols]) # column names. Use rbind to
                                                   # create two-row matrix.

        tempFisher <- fisher.test(tempMat, alternative="two.sided")
        results[row, resultsCol] <- tempFisher$p.value # Use row and column name
                                                       # indexing to assign
                                                       # p-value to results.
    }
}

# Compute adjusted p-values using all of the computed p-values, outside of loop.
padj <- results                           # First make copy of results matrix.  
padj[] <- p.adjust(results, method="fdr") # Trick to retain shape and attributes.
```

---

```
results
#                 Samp0_vs_Samp1 Samp0_vs_Samp2 Samp1_vs_Samp2
# chr10_101992307              1      1.0000000     1.00000000
# chr10_101992684              1      1.0000000     1.00000000
# chr10_127480585              1      1.0000000     1.00000000
# chr10_16479385               1      0.6436652     0.64366516
# chr10_73979859               1      1.0000000     1.00000000
# chr10_73979940               1      1.0000000     0.03290832

padj
#                 Samp0_vs_Samp1 Samp0_vs_Samp2 Samp1_vs_Samp2
# chr10_101992307              1              1      1.0000000
# chr10_101992684              1              1      1.0000000
# chr10_127480585              1              1      1.0000000
# chr10_16479385               1              1      1.0000000
# chr10_73979859               1              1      1.0000000
# chr10_73979940               1              1      0.5923497
```

Comment: Thank you! This does appear to work but I've noticed that when there are only two samples, I seem to run into an error trying to assign column names  to the results matrix: `Error in colnames<-(*tmp*, value = "ERR188028_GBR_vs_ERR188035_GBR") : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent` Any idea's as to why this is?

Comment: Fixed. It was an error in creating the results matrix (that just happened to work out for n=3 samples!) The results matrix needs to have one column for each possible pair: `ncol=ncol(pairwiseComb)`